# Need to transpose single column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `myDf` which looks like:

```
myDf = data.frame(
  a = c(1,1),
  b = c('A','B'),
  d = c(10,15),
  e = c(0,5)
)
```

Now I need to transpose column b such that my new data frame would like

```
myDf_transposed = data.frame(
  a = 1,
  A_d = 10,
  A_e = 0,
  B_d = 15,
  B_e = 5
)
```

I have tried:

```
library(reshape2)
myDf_tansposed <- recast(myDf, a  ~ b, id.var = c("b", "a","d","e"))
```

It transpose column b but I get warning

> Using 'e' as value column: use value.var to override.

Comment: `reshape(myDf, idvar = "a", timevar = "b", direction = "wide")` works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(myDf), a~b, value.var = c('d', 'e'))
```